# WPF clipping layout transform

Tags: wpf, rotation, layouttransform

I'm seeing a rotation issue that I have demonstrated in the code below.

Whilst the TextBlock is being rendered correctly, the ContentControl is being clipped.

It looks like it is clipping it to the width of the columndefinition and then applying the rotation?

I can get around the issue in the example by setting a width on the ContentControl, but in practise, I don't want to do that as I need it to automatically size to the width of its content.

```
 <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="Some long text">
            <TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                <RotateTransform Angle="90" />
            </TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
        </TextBlock>

        <ContentControl>
            <ContentControl.LayoutTransform>
                <RotateTransform Angle="90" />
            </ContentControl.LayoutTransform>

            <Button Content="Some Long Text..." />
        </ContentControl>
    </StackPanel>

    <Button Content="Button"
            Grid.Column="1" />
</Grid>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `Button` is clipped even if remove the `RotateTransform` from the `ContentControl`, isn't it?

It's because of the `StackPanel`. Replace it with a `Panel` that doesn't measures its children with an infinite height or width:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Text="Some long text">
        <TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
            <RotateTransform Angle="90" />
        </TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
    </TextBlock>

    <ContentControl Grid.Row="1">
        <ContentControl.LayoutTransform>
            <RotateTransform Angle="90" />
        </ContentControl.LayoutTransform>

        <Button Content="Some Long Text..." />
    </ContentControl>

    <Button Content="Button"
            Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: What I wanted was to have a panel in the first column that could stack items, and have each item auto size. In your example the items get stretched to fill the space. It's strange that it works for textblocks, but not other elements

Comment: Did you read my answer? Did you try to remove the `StackPanel`?

Comment: I did read your answer. But as I said above, I want the items to stack, so need a stacking panel behaviour

Comment: So why don't you use a `Grid` like in my example? If you still think it will work like you want or expect with a `StackPanel` then good luck := It  doesn't.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding. I need the items to stack like I showed in the image. Your solution stretches the items to fit, which isn't what I want.

Comment: I'm not suggesting I need a stack panel, I'm just trying to figure out how to get stacking behaviour, without clipping.